# Contact us to get started We weren’t able to establish your payments profile. To finish setting up your free trial, get help from our Support team

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was trying to set up my Google Cloud Platform free trial and after setting up my debit card, Google Cloud Platform deducted 1 in my local currency, they still told me that- Contact us to get started
We weren’t able to establish your payments profile. To finish setting up your free trial, get help from our Support team. How do o go about solving this issue because contacting support is not going through.